# Getting session and SFTP channel in Java using JSch library

Tags: java, refactoring, sftp, jsch, code-duplication

I am using JSch library for SFTP. I need to do several operations on SFTP server like move remote files in other directory, pull files, etc. For all these operations I need `Session` and from it I get `Channel` an then cast it to `ChannelSftp`. This is redundant step. So I thought of abstracting it into a `private` method.

```
private ChannelSftp getChannelSftp() throws JSchException
    {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session;
        session = jsch.getSession(VENDOR1_USERID, VENDOR1_SERVER, VENDOR1_PORT);
        session.setPassword(VENDOR1_PASSWORD);

        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        return channelSftp;
    }
```

But after the SFTP operation I need to disconnect from channel and session **both**.
With above method, though I can disconnect from `Channel` in the calling method but I can't disconnect from `Session` as I don't have its instance which might be a leak so I now separated that into `getSession()` method and now `ChannelSftp` creation is duplicated in all methods.

What is better way to ***design/refactor*** it?

```
private Session getSession() throws JSchException
    {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session;
        session = jsch.getSession(VENDOR1_USERID, VENDOR1_SERVER, VENDOR1_PORT);
        session.setPassword(VENDOR1_PASSWORD);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        return session;
    }
```

**Calling Method example:** - *Duplicated code indicated*

```
public void sftp(File file) throws  SftpException, FileNotFoundException, JSchException
    {
        Session session = getSession();
/* Duplicate code START*/
        if ( session == null ) throw new SftpException(0 , "Service: Session is NULL"); 

        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
/* Duplicate code END*/
        channelSftp.cd(VENDOR1_PATH);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());

        channelSftp.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the SFTP session frequently enough, you should not recreate it for every operation. Opening an SSH/SFTP connection is very CPU demanding, both for the client and the server. It's quite a waste to shutdown a connection, if you are going to need a new one shortly.

So consider opening a single shared session and channel at the beginning of your "application" and reuse it for all operations.

---

To answer your actual session: I'd introduce another class that owns both `Session` and `ChannelSftp` (with methods like `getSession()` and `getChannel()`) and return that from the factory method.

---

Though actually, there's [`getSession` method in the `Channel` class](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#getSession--).