# Move multiple files in a SFTP location in a single operation

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, mv

I have to move multiple files from folder A to B in a SFTP location. I am using Jsch library in java. Currently my implementation does it one by one by calling method **move** defined below.

Can we transfer it at one go as I have all the source file path already available - This will be more efficient instead of multiple IO communication back and forth.

```
    public default boolean move(String srcPath, String destPath) throws JSchException, SftpException
    {
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = getChannel();

        if (channelSftp == null)
            throw new SftpException(0, "Service: ChannelSftp is NULL");

        channelSftp.rename(srcPath, destPath);

        disconnect(channelSftp);

        return true;
    }

public default void disconnect(ChannelSftp channelSftp) throws JSchException
    {
        channelSftp.disconnect();
        Session session =  channelSftp.getSession();
        if(session != null)
            session.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no batch move operation in SFTP protocol. So there's no way to implement what you ask for.

---

But you should reuse the `ChannelSftp`. No need to open and close it for each move request. It actually looks like you even open/close whole SFTP connection for each request.

*What I actually suggested you half a year ago already in my answer to your [Getting session and SFTP channel in Java using JSch library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47451879/850848), to which you never bothered to even respond.*